# Finding largest files that do not contain a string

Tags: ubuntu, grep, find

I'm trying to re-encode my larger AVI/MKV files in X264 or older format on my media server. My idea is to find the largest files that not already encoded in HVEC (aka x265) format and convert them. To do so, I was using the following command in the home folder of my server (Ubuntu 14.04.6):

```
find . -printf '%s %p\n'|sort -nr|head -n 10
```

This works and adding 5 or 10 to the last number will show me the next 15 to 20 largest files, but I'd like to remove the already encoded into HVEC media files from the list to save time.

I've been able to use GREP to search for 'HVEC' with a command similar to this:

```
grep -Ril 'HEVC' .
```

As well as files that are not HEVC encoded with this command

```
grep -vRil x265 .
```

But I haven't been able to find a combination of the two commands to show the largest 10 files not already encoded. I'm basically trying to list the top 10 largest files that are not already in HVEC encode.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Grep might produce false positives. Use a proper metadata parser

Answer (score 0):

Using the `zsh` shell, the list of all regular files in the current directory and below, sorted in decreasing order by size, is given by the globbing pattern

```
./**/*(.NOL)
```

The `.` in the globbing qualifier `(.NOL)` makes the pattern only match regular files, while `N` makes the pattern expand to nothing if here is no match (as if `nullglob` had been used in `bash`), and `OL` orders the matches by length/size in decreasing order.

Going through these until a file that does not contain the string `x265`:

```
for pathname in ./**/*(.NOL); do
    if ! grep -qF 'x265' $pathname; then
        break
    fi
done
```

The value `$pathname` would then be the largest file not containing the string `x265`.

To get an array of these files, you could do

```
files=( ./**/*(.NOLe['! grep -qF x265 $REPLY']) )
```

To get an array of only the first 10 such files (i.e. the 10 largest files not containing the string `x265`):

```
files=( ./**/*(.NOLe['! grep -qF x265 $REPLY'][1,10]) )
```

To print the values of the array in a single column:

```
print -rC1 -- $files
```

To loop over the 10 files, use

```
for pathname in ./**/*(.NOLe['! grep -qF x265 $REPLY'][1,10])
do
    # process $pathname here
done
```

or

```
files=( ./**/*(.NOLe['! grep -qF x265 $REPLY'][1,10]) )
for pathname in $files; do
    # process $pathname here
done
```

---

Note that `grep -q -v expression` is *very different* from `! grep -q expression`.  The first would return *true* if there are lines that does not match `expression` while the second would return *true* if there are *no* lines matching `expression`.